# About the weighted norm for integralation

Tags: integration, harmonic-analysis

Let $w:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative, measurable function.

And we define a weighted integrable space $L^1(w)$ whose norm is defined by
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^1(w)}:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|w(x)dx
\end{equation}

My question: if $f\in L^1(w)$, is $f\cdot\chi_{B}$ (where $B$ is bounded ball centered at $0$) integrable in the usual sence? That is, if
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|w(x)dx<\infty,
\end{equation}
can we show
\begin{equation}
\int_{B}|f(x)|dx<\infty\ ?
\end{equation}

Please help me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any more information on w, not a lot can be said. 
For example, the obvious case $w=0$ springs to mind. We always have $\frac{1}{||\cdot ||} \in L^1(w)$ but it is never in $L^1(B)$.